# how to set input value based on sending anchor using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of OpenID's, and I'd like to populate an input field based on the sending anchor.

Basically the goal will be to populate the input with "**Google**" if the first button is clicked, "**Yahoo!**" for the second, etc.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

```
            <div>
                <div class="openid openid_large_btn google-large"> <a href="#" class="openid_btn" ><span>Google</span></a></div>
                <div class="openid openid_large_btn yahoo-large"><a href="#" class="openid_btn" ><span>Yahoo!</span></a></div>
                <div class="openid openid_large_btn myopenid-large"><a href="#" class="openid_btn"><span>myOpenID</span></a></div>
                <div class="openid openid_large_btn aol-large"><a href="#" class="openid_btn"><span>AOL</span></a></div>
                <div class="openid openid_large_btn facebook-large"><a href="#" class="openid_btn"><span>facebook</span></a></div>
            </div>

<script>
    $('.openid_btn').click(function () {

//I'd like to set this to the info contained within the <span> tags
        $("#openid_identifier").val("???"); 


        $('#OpenIDForm').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
$('.openid_btn').click(function () { 
    $("#openid_identifier").val($("span", $(this)).text());  
    $('#OpenIDForm').submit(); 
});
```

Comment: I knew it would be easy.. I just don't have the chops.  Thanks.

Comment: First, it should be `$("#openid_identifier").val($("span", this).text());`, but there's no need for that, since you can just get text off the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) directly on the clicked `<a>` since that's the only *text* that's in there, like this:

```
$('.openid_btn').click(function () { 
  $("#openid_identifier").val($(this).text());  
  $('#OpenIDForm').submit(); 
});
```

Or, a bit cheaper:

```
$("#openid_identifier").val($.text([this]));
```